# React-redux dispatch action onclick using hooks and redux toolkit

Tags: redux, react-redux, react-hooks, onclick, redux-toolkit

Fairly new to redux, react-redux, and redux toolkit, but not new to React, though I am shaky on hooks. I am attempting to dispatch an action from the click of a button, which will update the store with the clicked button's value. I have searched for how to do this high and low, but now I am suspecting I am thinking about the problem in React, without understanding typical redux patterns, because what I expect to be possible is just not done in the examples I have found. What should I be doing instead? The onclick does seem to capture the selection, but it is not being passed to the action. My goal is to show a dynamic list of buttons from data collected from an axios get call to a list of routes. Once a button is clicked, there should be a separate call to an api for data specific to that clicked button's route. Here is an example of what I currently have set up:

reducersRoutes.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { routesApiCallBegan } from "./createActionRoutes";

const slice = createSlice({
    name: "routes",
    initialState: {
        selected: ''
    },
{... some more reducers...}

        routeSelected: (routes, action) => {
            routes.selected = action.payload;
        }
    },
});

export default slice.reducer;

const { routeSelected } = slice.actions;

const url = '';

export const loadroutes = () => (dispatch) => {
    return dispatch(
        routesApiCallBegan({
            url,
{...}
            selected: routeSelected.type,
        })
    );
};
```

createActionRoutes.js

```
import { createAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

{...some other actions...}
export const routeSelected = createAction("routeSelection");
```

components/routes.js:

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { loadroutes } from "../store/reducersRoutes";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { routeSelected } from "../store/createActionRoutes";
import Generic from "./generic";


const Routes = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const routes = useSelector((state) => state.list);
    const selected = useSelector((state) => state.selected);
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadroutes());
}, [dispatch]);

const sendRouteSelection = (selection)  => {
    dispatch(routeSelected(selection))
}

return (
    <div>
        <h1>Available Information:</h1>
        <ul>
            {routes.map((route, index) => (
               <button key={route[index]} className="routeNav" onClick={() => sendRouteSelection(route[0])}>{route[1]}</button>
            ))}
        </ul>
        {selected !== '' ? <Generic /> : <span>Data should go here...</span>}
    </div>
);
};

export default Routes;
```

Would be happy to provide additional code if required, thanks!

ETA: To clarify the problem - when the button is clicked, the action is not dispatched and the value does not appear to be passed to the action, even. I would like the selection value on the button to become the routeSelected state value, and then make an api call using the routeSelected value. For the purpose of this question, just getting the action dispatched would be plenty help!

Comment: Can you clarify what the specific problem is atm?  It's not clear what the actual question is based on what you've said so far.  Which part is broken, not working, or you're having trouble implementing?

Comment: @markerikson, I added some clarification to the question, let me know if you need more info, thanks!

Comment: Hmm. The code seems okay at first glance. What do the `route` values look like? Any chance you can put this up as a CodeSandbox that actually runs? If you use the Redux DevTools Extension, does it show _any_ action being dispatched when you click the button? If so, what is inside `action.payload`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing that last comment, I may actually see a couple potential issues:

First, you're currently defining two *different* action types named `routeSelected`:

- One is in the routes slice, generated by the key `routeSelected`
- The other is in `createActionRoutes.js`, generated by the call to `createAction("routeSelection")`.

You're importing the second one into the component and dispatching it.  However, that is a different action type string name than the one from the slice - it's just `'routeSelection'`, whereas the one in the slice file is `'routes/routeSelected'`.  Because of that, the reducer logic in the slice file will never run in response to that action.

I don't think you want to have that separate `createAction()` call at all.  Do `export const { routeSelected } = slice.actions` in the slice file, and dispatch that action in the component.

I'm also a little concerned about the `loadroutes` thunk that you have there. I see that you might have omitted some code from the middle, so I don't know all of what it's doing, but it doesn't look like it's actually dispatching actions when the fetched data is retrieved.

I'd recommend looking into using RTK's `createAsyncThunk` API to generate and dispatch actions as part of data fetching - see [Redux Essentials, Part 5: Async Logic and Data Fetching](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic) for examples of that.